# Javascript string searching, double dot appears over the letter i

Tags: javascript, string, search, character-encoding

I'm trying to search a string variable (a city name that comes from an array) in another string (an address string). Here is the sample code :

```
    var cities = [....];
    var address ='....';
    var cityName ='';

    for(var i=0; i < cities.length){
        cityName = cities[i];
        console.log(cityName);

       if(address.search(cityName) > 0){
        return cityName;
       }

   }
```

But, even though there is not a special character problem in the cityName , search method returns -1 for an existing cityName.

Because, when i copy the cityName from the console and paste it to the js file again, it appears double dot on the i letter (i couldn't write here, it turned to normal i) so the method cannot find the city.

Is it an encoding problem or what?

S.O.S

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual data in question.

Comment: Help us identify the problem here? `"ï".indexOf("i") === -1`...If you search for `ï` is will find it and if you search for `i` it will not. They aren't the same letter.

Comment: Maybe you could sanitize the address and the cityName by replacing any accentuated character, before searching. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, but why is it happening? There's no any special characters both in the array and the address.

Comment: @OzgurO. `"Hï".search("Hï")` works. So you are probably trying to look for a single dotted i. `ï` and `i` are two distinct characters, so `"Hï".search("Hi")` won't work

Comment: streetName == "cemi̇l"  // this is the character

Comment: replaced the character with normal i then the problem solved. But it is for just one character. Pretty sure i'll be facing another character issues. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your problem right, but I'm assuming it's caused by a dieresis ("double dot on the i")? If so you might need to look into encoding those characters, here are the encoding for an i with dieresis

`Ï  \xCF    &#207;  &Iuml;  %CF %C3%8F  latin capital letter I with diaeresis`

`ï  \xEF    &#239;  &iuml;  %EF %C3%AF  latin small letter i with diaeresis`

more info: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm

Comment: Yes it is the problem. But the character is a little different. Like one dot over another dot. And how can you paste the special characters here? I checked the help for the comments but i couldn't find a way

Comment: @OzgurO. Ɉᵾsŧ ȼøᵽɏ Ⱥnđ ᵽȺsŧɇ

Comment: Yes i dit it the comments above. İt looks different though